# Firebase doesn't deploy. ERROR SELF SIGNED CERTIFICATE

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-analytics, console-application

I've been following the tutorial on how to apply Dialoglflow to an app... https://developers.google.com/actions/dialogflow/first-app#deploy_the_fulfillment

On the section BUILD FULFILLMENT, the error occurs. I've installed the latest node.js, python and installed npm on the directory. Yet the following errors occur. For some reason, I can't deploy firebase.

```js
C:\Users\Joshua\firebaseTest-1\functions>npm install
npm WARN chat-bot@0.0.1 No repository field.
npm WARN chat-bot@0.0.1 No license field.

up to date in 1.882s

C:\Users\Joshua\firebaseTest-1\functions>firebase deploy --only functions

=== Deploying to 'chat-bot'...

i  deploying functions
i  functions: ensuring necessary APIs are enabled...
+  functions: all necessary APIs are enabled
i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading...
i  functions: packaged functions (46.81 KB) for uploading
!  functions: Upload Error: Server Error. self signed certificate in certificate chain

Error: Server Error. self signed certificate in certificate chain

Having trouble? Try again or contact support with contents of firebase-debug.log

C:\Users\Joshua\firebaseTest-1\functions>npm config strict-ssl false
npm ERR! Usage:
npm ERR! npm config set <key> <value>
npm ERR! npm config get [<key>]
npm ERR! npm config delete <key>
npm ERR! npm config list [--json]
npm ERR! npm config edit
npm ERR! npm set <key> <value>
npm ERR! npm get [<key>]
npm ERR!
npm ERR! alias: c

C:\Users\Joshua\firebaseTest-1\functions>firebase deploy

Error: Server Error. getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND admin.firebase.com admin.firebase.com:443
```

My package.json

```js
{
    "name": "chat-bot",
    "description": "Find out your silly name!",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "author": "",
    "engines": {
        "node": "~4.2"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "actions-on-google": "^2.0.0",
        "firebase-admin": "~5.12.0",
        "firebase-functions": "^1.0.1"
    }
}
```

Firebase debug

```js
[debug] [2018-05-02T14:07:20.879Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200
[info] 
[info] === Deploying to 'chat-bot'...
[info] 
[info] i  deploying functions
[debug] [2018-05-02T14:07:24.128Z] > [functions] package.json contents: {
  "name": "chat-bot",
  "description": "Find out your silly name!",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "",
  "engines": {
    "node": "~4.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "actions-on-google": "^2.0.0",
    "firebase-admin": "~5.12.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^1.0.1"
  }
}
[info] i  functions: ensuring necessary APIs are enabled...
[debug] [2018-05-02T14:07:24.129Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST GET https://servicemanagement.googleapis.com/v1/services/cloudfunctions.googleapis.com/projectSettings/chat-bot?view=CONSUMER_VIEW  
  
 Wed May 02 2018 10:07:24 GMT-0400 (SA Western Standard Time)
[debug] [2018-05-02T14:07:24.130Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST GET https://servicemanagement.googleapis.com/v1/services/runtimeconfig.googleapis.com/projectSettings/chat-bot?view=CONSUMER_VIEW  
  
 Wed May 02 2018 10:07:24 GMT-0400 (SA Western Standard Time)
[debug] [2018-05-02T14:07:24.827Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200
[debug] [2018-05-02T14:07:24.963Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200
[info] +  functions: all necessary APIs are enabled
[debug] [2018-05-02T14:07:24.969Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST GET https://cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/v1/projects/chat-bot  
  
 Wed May 02 2018 10:07:24 GMT-0400 (SA Western Standard Time)
[debug] [2018-05-02T14:07:25.388Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200
[debug] [2018-05-02T14:07:25.389Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST GET https://mobilesdk-pa.googleapis.com/v1/projects/745144661921:getServerAppConfig  
  
 Wed May 02 2018 10:07:25 GMT-0400 (SA Western Standard Time)
[debug] [2018-05-02T14:07:25.839Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200
[info] i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading...
[debug] [2018-05-02T14:07:25.845Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST GET https://runtimeconfig.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/chat-bot/configs  
  
 Wed May 02 2018 10:07:25 GMT-0400 (SA Western Standard Time)
[debug] [2018-05-02T14:07:26.157Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200
[info] i  functions: packaged functions (46.81 KB) for uploading
[debug] [2018-05-02T14:07:26.661Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST POST https://cloudfunctions.googleapis.com/v1/projects/chat-bot/locations/us-central1/functions:generateUploadUrl  
  
 Wed May 02 2018 10:07:26 GMT-0400 (SA Western Standard Time)
[debug] [2018-05-02T14:07:27.288Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200
[debug] [2018-05-02T14:07:27.288Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST PUT https://storage.googleapis.com/gcf-upload-us-central1-a83f95b8-35cc-4cfe-ad36-21c12aa5388b/1d1b7de1-c643-4418-99fa-a39f76cd330b.zip?GoogleAccessId=745144661921@cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com&Expires=1525271696&Signature=j4ZSbM6Xrn56ujlM1nIYEr0zEU13BuVb%2B4hcdOp8uDduZwBlD1cSzNaSVLRx0mVyJSdCnvg8F6r0vts592cEgr8MLBe2CHcaBqNfT1BtDtRrfjdUKkdVC2qWlqG1IzfYbyUI7Ex8jQJLp6uxn22nlkJjGOTeK%2Flc3S%2FSTXFaya1a3apMWZ0oQqfSJOSMtIXkqgNN%2FU3wHrQRfeS6naiBvUTTP2QNrtnxLv5%2FV1SVxBbsvFb8hpwZWMnEuWq6IrT9E%2F4iQxa3QkHW6q3Q8zUhvBcYjC%2BdbZl85d91ApyQPD3shWPT2E2nlpLXY2rDMo%2FFpL%2FhnCjROm3FbSxwPeI%2FpA%3D%3D  
 ReadStream {
  _readableState: 
   ReadableState {
     objectMode: false,
     highWaterMark: 65536,
     buffer: BufferList { head: [Object], tail: [Object], length: 1 },
     length: 47931,
     pipes: null,
     pipesCount: 0,
     flowing: null,
     ended: true,
     endEmitted: false,
     reading: false,
     sync: false,
     needReadable: false,
     emittedReadable: true,
     readableListening: false,
     resumeScheduled: false,
     destroyed: false,
     defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
     awaitDrain: 0,
     readingMore: false,
     decoder: null,
     encoding: null },
  readable: true,
  domain: null,
  _events: { end: [Function] },
  _eventsCount: 1,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  path: 'C:\\Users\\Joshua\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\firebase-functions-4184WIPwqxjSP0OZ.zip',
  fd: 5,
  flags: 'r',
  mode: 438,
  start: 0,
  end: Infinity,
  autoClose: true,
  pos: 131072,
  bytesRead: 47931 } 
 Wed May 02 2018 10:07:27 GMT-0400 (SA Western Standard Time)
[warn] !  functions: Upload Error: Server Error. self signed certificate in certificate chain
[debug] [2018-05-02T14:07:27.973Z] Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain
    at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (_tls_wrap.js:1105:38)
    at emitNone (events.js:106:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:208:7)
    at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:639:8)
    at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:469:38)
[error] 
[error] Error: Server Error. self signed certificate in certificate chain
[debug] [2018-05-02T14:18:20.241Z] ----------------------------------------------------------------------
[debug] [2018-05-02T14:18:20.244Z] Command:       C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\Joshua\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\bin\firebase deploy
[debug] [2018-05-02T14:18:20.244Z] CLI Version:   3.18.4
[debug] [2018-05-02T14:18:20.244Z] Platform:      win32
[debug] [2018-05-02T14:18:20.244Z] Node Version:  v8.11.1
[debug] [2018-05-02T14:18:20.244Z] Time:          Wed May 02 2018 10:18:20 GMT-0400 (SA Western Standard Time)
[debug] [2018-05-02T14:18:20.244Z] ----------------------------------------------------------------------
[debug] 
[debug] [2018-05-02T14:18:20.253Z] > command requires scopes: ["email","openid","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloudplatformprojects.readonly","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"]
[debug] [2018-05-02T14:18:20.253Z] > authorizing via signed-in user
[debug] [2018-05-02T14:18:20.255Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST GET https://admin.firebase.com/v1/projects/chat-bot  
  
 Wed May 02 2018 10:18:20 GMT-0400 (SA Western Standard Time)
[debug] [2018-05-02T14:18:31.556Z] Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND admin.firebase.com admin.firebase.com:443
    at errnoException (dns.js:50:10)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:92:26)
[error] 
[error] Error: Server Error. getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND admin.firebase.com admin.firebase.com:443
```

Comment: Can you please provide firebase-debug.log

Comment: Edited @JonathanLafleur

Comment: There's might be a problem with your version of OpenSSL or it's not permitted to submit a self-signed certificate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Disable your anti-virus.
I paused my Kaspersky Internet Security. It worked like a charm.

Comment: Like a pice of cake

Comment: I'm in a corporate environment and this was caused by a firewall issue. I had to have googleapis.com whitelisted.